# How to add non-negativity constraints to an LP in SCPSolver?

Tags: java, linear-programming, scpsolver

I am using [SCPSolver](http://scpsolver.org/) for formulating linear problems in java.

Toy linear problem:

```
    min x + y
        x + 2y >= -1
        x - 2y >= -1
```

Can be written in java as:

```
LinearProgram lp = new LinearProgram(new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 });

lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[] { 1.0, 2.0 }, -1.0, "c1"));
lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[] { 1.0, -2.0 }, -1.0, "c2"));
lp.setMinProblem(true);

LinearProgramSolver solver = SolverFactory.newDefault();
double[] sol = solver.solve(lp);
```

Now to add non-negativity constraints on `x` and `y` I could add:

```
lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[] { 1.0, 0.0 }, 0.0, "c3"));
lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 }, 0.0, "c4"));
```

But is there a single function call to add non-negativity constraints for all the variables? something like `lp.addAllNonNegativityConstraints()`?

Comment: I think by default variables are non-negative. Otherwise call [setLowerbound](http://scpsolver.org/javadoc/scpsolver/problems/MathematicalProgram.html#setLowerbound(double[])).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for the link to docs. `setLowerbound` works!. But by default all variables are unbounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like this.

```
lp.setLowerbound(new double[lp.getDimension()]);
```

sets the lower bound for all variables to zero.